# Javascript post var_dump($_POST)

Tags: javascript, php

This is my ovhRecod.php:

```js
<!-- Place this tag after the last widget tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
     
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
} );
 
 
</script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="css/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>               
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div  style="overflow: auto;">
 
<?php
 
require_once ("OvhApi.php");
$phone = $_POST['name'];
echo $phone;
     
//echo '<pre>';var_dump($_POST);
// Action de test demandée
$action = @$_GET["action"];
           // connexion
             $cnx = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Impossible de se connecter");
             $db = mysql_select_db("$bdd") or die("Impossible de se connecter");
                $requete  = "SELECT billingAcount
                            FROM persons
                            WHERE phone=".$phone;
                $resultat = mysql_query($requete);
                while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($resultat)) {
            $billingAcount = $data['billingAcount'];
    }
 
$ovh = new OvhApi();
$resp = $ovh->get('/telephony/'.$billingAcount.'/easyHunting/'.$phone.'/records');
sort($resp);
echo "<table id='table_id' class='table-style-two'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th> Début de l'appel</th>
          <th>    Fin de l'appel</th>
          <th>   Numéro appelant</th>
          <th>   Agent</th>
          <th> Durée</th>
          <th>    Ecoute</th>
          <th>Telechargement</th>
          </tr>
        </thead><tbody>";
    foreach ($resp as $valeur) {
    $test = $ovh->get('/telephony/'.$billingAcount.'/easyHunting/'.$phone.'/records/'.$valeur);
    $nameAgent = $ovh->get('/telephony/'.$billingAcount.'/line/'.$test['agent']);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".date('d/n/Y',strtotime($test['callStart']))." ".date('H:i',strtotime($test['callStart']))."                  "."</td>";
    echo "<td>".date('d/n/Y',strtotime($test['callEnd']))." ".date('H:i',strtotime($test['callEnd']))."                   "."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['callerIdName']."                 "."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['agent']." - ".$nameAgent['description']."                 "."</td>";
    echo "<td><center>".$test['duration']." sec"."</center></td>";
    echo "<td>   <audio controls='controls' preload='none'><source src=".$test['fileUrl']."></audio> </td>";
    echo "<td>   <center><a href=".$test['fileUrl'].">Télécharger</a></center></td>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
 
?>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

    </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

I got a problem on a JS Post. Here is my code:

```js
</FORM>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {
  
      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();
     
$.post("ovhRecord.php", {name: $('#phone').val()}, function(r){ $("#div1").html(r); });
 
    });
</script>
```

```html
    <FORM method="post" action="ovhRecord.php" id="formoid">
      <?php
       // connexion
         $cnx = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Impossible de se connecter");
         $db = mysql_select_db("$bdd") or die("Impossible de se connecter");
            $requete2="SELECT *
                        FROM persons AS p, tbl_users AS u
                        WHERE p.user_id=u.user_id
                        And u.user_id =".$_SESSION['user_session'];
            $result2=mysql_query($requete2);
             
            while ($ligne=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
            {
                echo '<button type="submit" name="phone" style="width:99%;" value="'.$ligne["phone"].'">'.$ligne["nomLigne"].'</button></br>';
            }
    ?>
     </FORM>
```

My `$.post("ovhRecord.php", {name: $('#phone').val()}` doesn't return anything in `ovhRecord.php`. When I do a `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST);` it's returning:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Does anyone have a idea?

Comment: Please show what the markup that this code produces looks like. I suspect $ligne["phone"] might be empty/null

Comment: Is there any "<input>" in your form ? there has to be some data in your form before putting it in the submit...

Comment: the  $ligne["phone"] is not null/empty cose when i run the fill without JS i got a ECHO with data

Comment: please add the generated HTML

Comment: a etit my answer in the post as you went

Comment: any one have a idea?

Comment: `$('#phone').val()` - there is no element with id "phone" in your HTML as far as I can see. There's one (or potentially more than one, since it's generated in a loop) with _name_ = phone, although it's a button, which is an unconventional way of including post data - buttons are for clicking, not data transfer (although they do get included in the POST data, for some reason).

Comment: As an aside, I hope this isn't new code you're writing - the mysql_xx PHP extension has been deprecated for several years and is removed entirely in the new PHP7. It's got security vulnerabilities. Additionally, your code is wide open to SQL injection - switch to using the PDO or MySQLi libraries and use paramterised queries, otherwise you are wide open to hacking.